# Non-public API usage with _pb_ methods

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, google-mobile-ads

Steps to reproduce:

After sending a new build to the AppStore Connect and while processing I get this Email from Apple:

> ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public
>   symbols in Frameworks/Name.framework/Name: _pb_decode,
>   _pb_decode_varint, _pb_encode, _pb_encode_string, _pb_encode_submessage, _pb_encode_tag_for_field, _pb_encode_varint, _pb_istream_from_buffer, _pb_ostream_from_buffer, _pb_read. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above,
>   altering your method names will help prevent this app from being
>   flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of
>   the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included
>   with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further information,
>   visit the Technical Support Information at
>   http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

These methods are used in GoogleAppMeasurement framework (I have found them by grep).

I have updated all pods, changed the build number, etc. The result is the same - email from Apple.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4338

Comment: Nanopb seems to be used internally by Apple now. Possible options of how to get around it https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb/issues/448#issuecomment-548236167